# How do I take the integral of a real number over a complex region?

Tags: complex, integral-equations

If $A$ is a constant, real number with respect to $\tau$ and $\tau$ is an imaginary number, then how would I compute the integral in Mathematica?$$f(\tau)=\int A\space d\tau$$$$\tau=ir$$$$f(r)=Ai\int dr$$$$f(r)=i(Ar+V_0)$$How would I perform the same operation in Mathematica?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: $Integrate[A, I]$ and $Integrate[A, \left\{\tau, I, I*2\right\}]$ The latter gives a definite integral which appears to make sense, but I can't get the indefinite integral to work. Logic tells me it should be $i(A\tau+V_0)$.

Comment: @QuarkSoup, please edit the question and include the code that you have tried. Do not wrap it in dollar symbols, but with backticks ```.

Comment: Can you formulate the definition of $\int A\space d\tau$, where $\tau$ is an imaginary number? I've never met it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In calculus class we called the first three TeX'ed lines in the OP, the method of substitution. It's not particularly connected with complex numbers. It's just that your equation has an `I` in it.
In Mathematica it's done this way:

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][a, t], r, t == I*r] // 
 Activate
```

Or this way, to get the 4th line in the OP, in which the constant of integration comes out of the blue but can be managed with the `GeneratedParameters` option:

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][a, t], r, t == I*r] // 
 Append[GeneratedParameters -> (I*v[# - 1] &)] // 
  Activate
```

(`IntegrateChangeVariables` is fairly young and not very robust. It works on simple integrals but not ones with options. So add the options after.)

Note that all variables in Mathematica are assumed to be complex numbers (with some exceptions such as in optimization functions and explicitly non-complex functions such as `RealAbs[]`, `Surd[]` and `UnitStep[]`). In `Integrate[]`, the variables `a`, `tau` (`t`), and `r` are treated as complex. And`I * r` is not an imaginary number but `I` times a complex number. Likewise `v[0]` represents a complex number. There is no useful distinction between a real antiderivative and a complex antiderivative for most functions and not for constant functions.

Comment: *"And I * r is not an imaginary number but I times a complex number"* I'm not sure I understand this. Did you mean to say *"And I * r is not an imaginary number but I times a **real** number"*?

Comment: @QuarkSoup A variable in `Integrate` represents by default a complex number. So `r` represents a complex number. Of course every real numbers is also a complex number. And as a `Symbol`, `r` is not an actual number, so just because `r` can be a nonreal complex number does not prevent you from substituting only real values or later restricting it to be real in other functions. Perhaps this is simpler: The result of `Integrate` is valid if you substitute real or nonreal complex numbers for `r`.

Comment: Thank you. It would be very helpful if you could also provide the derivative operation that would get me back to **a**. If I take **D[i(ar+v0),r]**, I get **ai**. What is the proper way to take a derivative with the same logic.

Comment: @QuarkSoup I think you must want $d/dt$ of the expression, which would yield `a`. `D[.., t]` finds the **partial** derivative $\partial/\partial t$, so you need to apply the Chain Rule: $${d\over dt}={1\over\partial t/\partial r}\;{\partial\over\partial r}={1\over i}\;{\partial\over\partial r}$$ — An alternative is to use `Dt[]` which finds the total differential, a bit cumbersome since you have to declare constants. Example: `Block[{a, v}, SetAttributes[a, Constant]; SetAttributes[v, Constant]; Dt[y, t] /. First@Solve[{Dt[y == I (a r + v), t], Dt[t == I r, t]}, {Dt[y, t]}, {Dt[r, t]}]]`

Answer (score 3):

May be

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ode  = D[f[ τ ],τ]==A;
sol  = DSolveValue[ode,f[τ],τ]
sol  = sol/.{τ->I*r,C[1]->C[1]*I}
Simplify[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This looks very good, but I'm a little disappointed there's no built in ability to handle the integral over an imaginary region. Any idea why I can't do this with the Integral function?

Comment: I am not (yet) an expert on these matters and I can't come up with a specific scenario that would make this wrong, but it seems to me that you do need the reverse product rule to properly deal with the fact that we take the integral by $i\tau$ (which is a product, after all). What you're doing here is simple symbol swapping with
$$sol  = sol/.{τ->I*r,C[1]->C[1]*I}$$