# How do I find the definite double integral of a real number over a complex region?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

This is a follow-up question of [*How do I take the integral of a real number over a complex region?*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/289313/how-do-i-take-the-integral-of-a-real-number-over-a-complex-region)
Given that $\tau'$ is imaginary, how would you calculate the definite double integral over a complex region?$$v(\tau')=\int A\space d\tau'$$$$\tau'=i\tau$$$$v(\tau)=Ai\int d\tau$$$$v(\tau)=i(A\tau+V_0)$$So what I want to know is:$$x(\tau')=\int_{\tau_0}^{\tau_1}\int A 
\space d\tau'$$That is, given an imaginary evolution parameter and a constant, real acceleration, how would I find the distance between two events: $\tau_0$ and $\tau_1$? The code in the accepted answer (to the previous question) works well enough to get me to the first integral:

```
v[τ_] = Simplify[Activate[Append[IntegrateChangeVariables[           
 Inactive[Integrate][A, τPrime], τ, τPrime == I*τ],
  GeneratedParameters -> I*V &)]]]
```

and it's easy enough to get the second integral:

```
x[τ] = Activate[IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][v[τ],
 τPrime], τ, τPrime == I*τ]]]
```

But I can't seem to get the second step to work as a definite integral. It appears I'm running into a limitation of the `IntegrateChangeVariables` function.

**So my question is:** is the following formula a valid way around the limitation?

```
Simplify[(x[τ] /. {τ -> τ1}) - (x[τ] /. {τ -> τ0})]
```

**Follow up question:** Is there a better (more elegant) way in Mathematica way to derive the formula for distance over a complex region?